# How to set embedded struct fields in Kotlin/Native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Kotlin cinterop has generated such a wrapper for a C struct:

```kotlin
@kotlinx.cinterop.internal.CStruct public final class _GtkAccelGroupEntry public constructor(rawPtr: kotlinx.cinterop.NativePtr /* = kotlin.native.internal.NativePtr */) : kotlinx.cinterop.CStructVar {
    @kotlinx.cinterop.internal.CStruct.VarType public companion object : kotlinx.cinterop.CStructVar.Type {
    }

    public final var accel_path_quark: gtk3.GQuark /* = kotlin.UInt */ /* compiled code */

    public final var closure: kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<gtk3.GClosure /* = gtk3._GClosure */>? /* compiled code */

    public final val key: gtk3.GtkAccelKey /* = gtk3._GtkAccelKey */ /* compiled code */
}
```

The last field (key) is `val`, I assume because it's also a structure wrapper.

Is there any way to initialize such a field without resorting to unsafe memory access?

here's the original C struct:

```c
struct _GtkAccelKey
{
  guint           accel_key;
  GdkModifierType accel_mods;
  guint           accel_flags : 16;
};

struct _GtkAccelGroupEntry
{
  GtkAccelKey  key;
  GClosure    *closure;
  GQuark       accel_path_quark;
};
```

Comment: For simple cases it's possible to just replace all fields but for nested structs it must be done recursively. If someone knows why compiler has this limitation, I would like to know

Comment: Please extend the question with an example of actions you'd like to perform. I answered as much as I understood the problem and might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but, as far as I know, there are no approaches available other than direct manipulation. I found a [discussion](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C3SGXARS6/p1593990644146500) at the kotlinlang Slack, might be related.